# getElementsByClassName('container').style.display='block'; somehow doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with code getElementsByClassName('container').style.display='block'; somehow it doesnt work when I click on a button with this code:

I also can upload this script to my website so you an see if needed.

```
<div id="startStopBtn" onclick="startStop()"></div>
```

It should show up this code and it doesn't do so:

```
<div class="container">
            <center><?php echo $small_ads_id ; ?></center>
        <div id="test">
            <div class="testGroup" id="nomob">
                <div class="testArea">
                    <div class="icontest"><i class="fas fa-unlink"></i></div>
                    <div class="testName">Jitter</div>
                    <canvas id="jitMeter" class="meter"></canvas>
                    <div id="jitText" class="meterText"></div>
                    <div class="unit">ms</div>
                </div>
                <div class="testArea">
                    <div class="icontest"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></div>
                    <div class="testName">Ping</div>
                    <canvas id="pingMeter" class="meter"></canvas>
                    <div id="pingText" class="meterText"></div>
                    <div class="unit">ms</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="testGroup">
                <div class="testArea">
                <div class="testAreastyle">
                    <div class="icontest"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></div>
                    <div class="testName">Download</div>
                </div>  
                    <canvas id="dlMeter" class="meter"></canvas>
                    <div id="dlText" class="meterText"></div>
                    <div class="unit">Mbps</div>
                </div>
                <div class="testArea">
                    <div class="icontest"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></div>
                    <div class="testName">Upload</div>
                    <canvas id="ulMeter" class="meter"></canvas>
                    <div id="ulText" class="meterText"></div>
                    <div class="unit">Mbps</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: none; " id="ipArea">
                IP Address: <span id="ip"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(initUI,100);</script>
        <div class="fbdiv">
            <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;<?php echo $website_url ; ?>>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fblink">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> Share on Facebook 
            </a>
        </div>  
        </br>
        <center>
            <?php echo $big_ads_id ; ?>         
        </br>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div id="counter-area-winkey">Real time <span id="counter-winkey"></span> visitors right now</div>
            <script>
                function r(t,r){return Math.floor(Math.random()*(r-t+1)+t)}var interval=2e3,variation=5,c=r(500,2e3);$("#counter-winkey").text(c),setInterval(function(){var t=r(-variation,variation);c+=t,$("#counter-winkey").text(c)},interval);
            </script>
        </center>
    </div>
```

The startStop funcion:

```
function startStop(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('container').style.display='block';
        if(w!=null){
            w.postMessage('abort');
            w=null;
            data=null;
            I("startStopBtn").className="";
            initUI();
        }else{
            w=new Worker('netspeed/speedtest_worker.min.js');
            w.postMessage('start'); 
            I("startStopBtn").className="running";
            w.onmessage=function(e){
                data=JSON.parse(e.data);
                var status=data.testState;
                if(status>=4){
                    I("startStopBtn").className="";
                    w=null;
                    updateUI(true);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Thanks for reply

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('container')` will give you an array of DOM elements so you might wanna add `[0]` indexing while setting getting the stylings

Comment: There is just one 'class' in this script called 'container' should I change it to Id?

Comment: Yes you can but then you'll have to add an id attribute in that div. Getting anything with class name always gives an array because your html can have more than one elements with same class name. While id is unique for one dom element in the entire html page so that's why get element by id gives one dom element.

Comment: See if it works in case of Id then change it other wise try using queryselector() . Generally such things doesn't happen like it should work with all the cases(queryselector,getElementById OR getElementByClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list. So, you have to add an index there.
If that `container` class is on 1 element only then just write

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].style.display = block
//see the [0] after ('container')
```

If there are multiple elements having `container` class then you might want to loop through all of them with a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName gives a list object of the elements which have the class name.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('container')).forEach(container => container.style.display = 'none');
```

or

```
function setStyleProp(element, prop, val) {
    let elements = [];
    
    if (element instanceof HTMLElement) elements = [element];
    else if (typeof element === 'object') elements = Object.values(element);

    elements.forEach(el => el.style[prop] = val);
    return elements;
}

setStyleProp(document.getElementsByClassName('container'), 'display', 'none');
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list.

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("containerClass")].forEach(
    (container) => {
        return (container.style.display = 'none')
    }
);
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.